# What is a common term for the slide-able "info panel" on the bottom of certain smartphone apps?

Tags: information, collapsible-panels

I'm developing a smartphone application that displays a Google map. When a user taps a place on the map (for example, a restaurant), I want to display an "info panel" on the bottom of the app that displays the name of the touched location, plus other info. Similar to Google Maps, I want the user to be able to touch and drag upwards this info panel to view additional information. For example, in the image below, touching and dragging "Gardening Supplies in NY" upwards will display more information such as reviews, hours of operation, etc. My question is, what is a common term to refer to this sort of "slide-able info panel"?

[image: Google Maps example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it a "Drawer" (such as the [app drawer on Android](http://www.beginandroid.com/appdrawer.shtml)), but there are many possible terms for this kind of thing (tray, slide-up overlay, popup, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [snackbar](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage):

[image: snackbar demo]

As per Google's material design guide, the properties are:

- Single-line snackbar height: 48dp
- Multi-line snackbar height: 80dp
- Text: Roboto Regular 14sp
- Action button: Roboto Medium 14sp, all-caps text
- Default background fill: #323232 100%

Comment: These don't appear to be the same thing. Snackbars are meant to show minimal information about an action that has just been done, with up to 1 possible action to take. I'm talking about a slide-able view that a user can drag upward to get more information.